# SOAP::Lite and dateTime values

Tags: web-services, perl, datetime, soap

I am building a perl based SOAP request to send to a web service running on an IIS server.  The web service interface defines the arguments to the method as:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <MyMethodName xmlns="http://third.party.Web.Service/">
      <thing1>string</thing1>
      <StartTime>dateTime</StartTime>
      <EndTime>dateTime</EndTime>
    </MyMethodName>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The WSDL definition ins:

```
<s:element name="MyMethodName ">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="thing1" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="StartDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EndDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Formatting a date string is not a hard thing.  I am pulling the values from a database and I easily see the [dateTime definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime).  Crafting that format is trivial.  However, I always get the error:

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

My searches show posts that say to make sure the date string is formatted correctly.  I have hand coded the strings and relied on two SOAP::Lite related helper modules to deal with dateTime formatting.

The relevant bits of my current code include:

```
use SOAP::Lite;
use SOAP::DateTime qw(ConvertDate);

$soapResult = $soap->MyMethodName(
    SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('thing1')->value("my thing"),
    SOAP::Data->type('xsd:dateTime')->name('StartDate')->value(ConvertDate($row->{Start})),
    SOAP::Data->type('xsd:dateTime')->name('EndDate')->value(ConvertDate($row->{End})));
```

I am currently trying a "type" of "xsd:dateTime" but i ahve also tried "s:dateTime" and "dateTime".  Everything ends with the same error.

Comment: Have you tried turning tracing on to see what is really being sent?     use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'all';

Comment: I had not tried adding trace but i have now.  the values all look right.  They are all of the form:  

    <StartDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-08-22T15:54:28</StartDate>

which is exactly what i was entering in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble with this before and I ended up just building the SOAP request by hand. Possibly using a working request from elsewhere.

Alternatively I saw this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995764.aspx which details connecting to a .NET based service from perl

This might be the relevant bit

```
use SOAP::Lite;

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> uri('http://third.party.Web.Service/')
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', 'http://third.party.Web.Service', $_[1] } )
    -> proxy('ttp://third.party.Web.Service/<YOUR SERVICE HERE>.asmx');

my $method = SOAP::Data->name('MyMethodName')
    ->attr({xmlns => 'http://www.alfredbr.com/'});

my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name('s:string' => 'my thing'), 
           SOAP::Data->name('s:startTime' => $startTime),
           SOAP::Data->name('s:endTime' => $endTime) );

print $soap->call($method => @params)->result;
```

where your parameters are s:string, s:startTime and s:endTime and $startTime and $endTime have been set.

Can you possibly post the service you are trying to consume?

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try "coercing" the data type in the morning.  I am doing everything else your code sample suggests.

I can not expose the service due to contract issues.

Answer (score 0):

sigh, my bad.  I mis-typed the date related argument names.  This all works.